# Icon Above Link in GoJS

Tags: javascript, css, svg, gojs

In GoJS, is it possible to display an icon above a link such that when the link moves, the icon will also move?

For example, I'd like something that looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj0yL.jpg), but when either node is moved, the icon moves as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly -- just add a **GraphObject** to your link template.  By default such a "label" (which need not only be a **TextBlock**, but can be arbitrarily complex **Panel**s of objects) will be at the mid-point of the link.  You can set properties on the label object to control where and how it is arranged along the path of the link.

Something like:

```
myDiagram.linkTemplate =
  $(go.Link,
    $(go.Shape),  // the path
    $(go.Shape, { toArrow: "Standard" }),  // the arrowhead
    $(go.Picture, ...,   // your label implemented by a Picture showing an image
      {
        width: ..., height: ...,
        // with this offset relative to the mid point of the link path
        segmentOffset: new go.Point(0, -15)
      })
  );
```

Read more at http://gojs.net/latest/intro/linkLabels.html

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to dynamically add/remove this icon from arbitrary links?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to either set or bind the **GraphObject.visible** property on the label (the **Picture** in your case).  The Flow Chart sample does that, depending on whether a link is coming out of a "Decision" node or just a regular node, because one only wants links coming out of "Decision" nodes to have labels.